# Remove an amount from a string - Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have a string like "Renew B 6 Months 12.87 USD 1M A". From this i would like to remove the amount 12.87 USD, how can i do that in JavaScript. Thanks

Comment: i think we will need a larger sampling of your data to see a pattern that can be used to extract that.  can you include any more information? will it always be 17 characters in?  will it always be after 2 "words" a number and another word?  does it always have a decimal? with 2 digits?

Answer (score 1):

Match it with this regex:

```
\s+[\d,]+(?:\.\d+)? USD\s+
```

And use `.replace()`:

```
> 'Renew B 6 Months 12.87 USD 1M A'.replace(/\s+[\d,]+(?:\.\d+)? USD\s+/, ' ');
"Renew B 6 Months 1M A"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str="Renew B 6 Months 12.87 USD 1M A";
str=str.replace("12.87 USD ", "");
alert(str); // Renew B 6 Months 1M A
```

If it's static string otherwise you need to use a regular expression. Here **Blender** has gave an answer, take a look at his answer.